# How to check the opcode of an instruction?

Tags: llvm

In fact I have found two solutions, and I want to know if there is any difference:

- using isa, like `isa<LoadInst>(i)`
- using getopcode (`i.getopcode()` method and comparing to Load)

Which one should I use to check the opcode of an instruction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`isa` is used to check for an existing derived instruction class.  class `i.getopcode()` could help you to get all of the operations' information.

According to [the Inheritance diagram for `llvm::Instruction`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html),LLVM internally will divide all instructions into several different classes like `llvm::BinaryOperator`, `llvm::CallInst`, `llvm::CmpInst`, etc. But there is no exact operation information for these classes.

However, for `Instruction::getOpcode()`, it will directly get the operation from the `llvm::Instruction` object. You could refer to [Instruction.def](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/cbde0d9c7be1991751dc3eb5928294d2e00ef26a/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Instruction.def)  for an idea about definition of each instruction. Basically, the opcode will be the exact operations the instruction intends to do.

Say, for an LLVM IR `add`, you can use `isa<llvm::BinaryOperator>` to know that this is a `BinaryOperator`. But this is only for what the instruction class it is. If you want to know whether it is an `ADD` or a `SUB`. `i.getopcode()` should be used here.

Comment: Thank you. So since I'm only interrested in checking if the instruction is a Load or Store, I can keep using isa<LoadInst>(i) and isa<StoreInst>(i) without changing to if (i.getopcode()==...)?

Comment: Basically, yes. Since load, store have its own instruction class.